# Select corresponding to row from the same table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get some column based on another column

Example table:

```
| BlilCode | BlilShortName | BatchWeigth | BillVersion | BlilMaxTime |
+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 5502     | aaa           | 1.00        | 1           | 360         |
| 5502     | aaa           | 2.00        | 2           | 240         |
| 5510     | bbb           | -32.94      | 2           | 360         |
| 5510     | bbb           | 1.00        | 1           | 360         |
| 5510     | bbb           | 36.37       | 3           | 3600        |
```

but I want to get the rows where `BillVersion` is max for every `BlilCode` is max

Expected result

```
| BlilCode | BlilShortName | BatchWeigth | BillVersion | BlilMaxTime |
+----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 5502     | aaa           | 2.00        | 2           | 240         |
| 5510     | bbb           | 36.37       | 3           | 3600        |
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT    
    [BlilCode], [BlilShortName], 
    BatchWeigth, (BillVersion) AS BillVersion, [BlilMaxTime]
FROM 
    [CVfeedDB].[dbo].[constants.Blil]  
WHERE 
    BlilActive = 1 AND BatchWeigth IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    BlilCode
```

Comment: you chose the wrong answer.

Comment: @danihp they are both right but Radim answer is more closer to what i was trying to do so i choose it

Comment: @danihp why do you think so?

Comment: @RadimBača , Because I didn't read right the OP question. Now I see OP wants ALL rows with the max value, then your answer is right. Sorry about inconvenience. But checking question history, before editions, it said _'but i want to get the row's where BillVersion ...'_ Then, I don't know if your answer is right because it was posted before question editions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really smart from your description, however, the result can be achieved using the following query

```
select your_table.*
from your_table 
join
(
  select BlilShortName, max(billversion) bmax
  from your_table
  group by BlilShortName
) t on your_table.billversion = t.bmax and your_table.BlilShortName = t.BlilShortName
```

From my experience it can be faster in some cases when compared to `row_number` solution which always uses sequential scan.

**PERFORMANCE BONUS**

Since there is a discussion regarding the efficiency I dare to add simple test

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE dbo.GTable
SELECT TOP 1000000
      NEWID() id, 
      ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100 group_id, 
      ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10000 orderby
 INTO GTable
FROM    sys.sysobjects
CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns

SET STATISTICS TIME on
-- GROUP BY version
select t1.*
from gtable t1
join
    (
      SELECT group_id, max(orderby) gmax
      from gtable
      group by group_id
    ) t2 on t1.group_id = t2.group_id and t1.orderby = t2.gmax

-- WINDOW FUNCTION version
select t.id, t.group_id, t.orderby
from
(
select *, 
       dense_rank() over (partition by group_id order by orderby desc) rn
from gtable 
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

If I run this on my server then the performance of GROUP BY version is more than twice better than the window function version. Moreover, if I create index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_gtable_groupid_orderby
    ON [dbo].[GTable] (group_id,orderby) INCLUDE (id)
```

then the performance is even more than three times better, whereas the performance of window function solution is the same since it uses sequential scan despite the index.

Comment: Kudos to adding the test.  I accept it, but the window function should be using the index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, I would expect it to use it as well, since the major drawback of window function solution is a sort. However, it is not used at all, there is just a heap table scan.

Answer (score 2):

Your results suggest that you want:

```
select db.*
from (select db.*,
             row_number() over (partition by shortname order by billversion desc) as seqnum
      from db
     ) db
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you based this on `blilcode`, then the results would have three rows instead of two.

Note:  The question was edited after this, so the appropriate query would be:

```
select db.*
from (select db.*,
             row_number() over (partition by blilcode order by billversion desc) as seqnum
      from db
     ) db
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What about a CTE approach?

Comment: @danihp it would be the same

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , why 3 rows, in the example DB you only have 2 different blilcode

Comment: @danihp depends on who you are :) Different tastes.

Comment: @styx then it will give you 2 rows now

Comment: @styx . . . You should be aware that window functions are usually more efficient than `group by` and `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do not agree, please see my edited answer.