# sql fetch one record per date from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like:

```
o_id  order_no   date        etc....
 4     1         2017-02-01
 4     2         2017-02-01
 4     3         2017-02-01
```

what i want is only one(highest order no) record per date should be fetched.
For example for only order_no 3 for o_id 4 should be fetched

Output:

```
o_id       order_no      date
4          3             2017-02-01
2          1             .........so on
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS`? Expected Output? Code you tried?

Comment: i am using postgres. Output something like:  i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

The canonical method is to use the ANSI-standard `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by o_id order by order_no desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `GROUP BY` and `MAX` if the `order_no` is unique in each `o_id` group

```
select your_table.*
from your_table
join
(
  select o_id, max(order_no) maxorder
  from your_table
  group by o_id
) t on t.o_id = your_table.oid and t.maxorder = your_table.order_no
```

**Similar questions**

[Select corresponding to row from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server/47675014#47675014) - you can find there a performance comparison of group by and window function version, however, the comparison is for SQL Server.