# PostgreSQL - Joining latest record to group by result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below works as intended, but you guys sometimes can do magic when it comes to optimization. Is this all right or it can be done in better/faster way?

```
WITH last_events AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (type, adid)
        type,
        adid,
        value,
        created_at
    FROM public.adid
    ORDER BY type, adid, created_at DESC
)
SELECT
    adid.type,
    adid.adid,
    count(*) as count,
    sum(adid.value) as summary,
    le.created_at
FROM public.adid
JOIN last_events le ON le.type = adid.type AND le.adid = adid.adid
GROUP BY adid.type, adid.adid, le.created_at
ORDER BY summary DESC, le.created_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that certain parts of your solution are unnecessary. The CTE returns max `created_at` per `(type,adid)` group. The main query computes number of rows per `(type,adid)` group and sum of `value` per `(type,adid)` group. Therefore, it can be written like this

```
SELECT
    adid.type,
    adid.adid,
    count(*) as count,
    sum(adid.value) as summary,
    max(adid.created_at) max_created_at
FROM public.adid
GROUP BY adid.type, adid.adid
ORDER BY summary DESC, max_created_at DESC;
```

If you are interested in other columns corresponding to the row with highest `created_at` then you can use one of the classical greatest-per-group approaches. One that I prefer is to use `GROUP BY` to find the greatest value (very similar to your approach):

```
SELECT
    adid.type,
    adid.adid,
    t.count,
    t.summary,
    t.max_created_at,
    adid.value
FROM public.adid
JOIN (
  SELECT
    adid.type,
    adid.adid,
    count(*) as count,
    sum(adid.value) as summary,
    max(adid.created_at) max_created_at
  FROM public.adid
  GROUP BY adid.type, adid.adid
) t ON t.type = adid.type and 
       t.adid = adid.adid and 
       t.max_created_at = adid.created_at
ORDER BY t.summary DESC, t.max_created_at DESC;
```

I believe it is better like this since my solution has just one aggregation. Your solution use `DISTINCT ON` (which is hidden aggregation) and another `GROUP BY` in the outer join.

Another option to find greatest-per-group is to use window function, however, I think aggregation is a much better solution for your problem since you need more aggregation values. Moreover, `GROUP BY` seems to have a better performance in [certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server) than the window functions.

Comment: What if I would like to add other columns from latest record? [type, adid, count, summary, last_created_at, last_value]