# Data filter by max value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a long query that at the end return me over than 10K rows. Some of them appears twice due to multiply request Id's.
I wonder how can I update my query to take only the MAX values according to "material_request_id"  .

my query:

```
SELECT 
 distinct vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_name
,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id
 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.parttype_name
 ,operation_code
 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name
 ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.qdf_number
  , requestor
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].recipient_name
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_by
      ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_datetime as time1
      , DATEPART(WW,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_datetime) as WW
      ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.product_code_name
      ,task_name
      ,vw_public_request_material_location_mir.full_location_name

  FROM [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_request_material_location_mir]
         left join request on vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id = request.request_key
        left join vortex_dbo.material_request on vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id = vortex_dbo.material_request.material_request_id
        left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location on (vw_public_request_material_location_mir.last_result_id = vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.last_result_id 
        or vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_id = vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_id)
 left join vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_history on  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id like (substring(vw_public_material_history.comments,12,6)) 

  where (vw_public_request_material_location_mir.qdf_number not like 'null' and vw_public_request_material_location_mir.qdf_number  not like '')
  and operation_code not like '7757'
  and vw_public_request_material_location_mir.product_code_name like 'cannon LAKE%'
  and vw_public_request_material_location_mir.task_id not like 'null'
  and (vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'bin 100' or  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'bin 01'
   or  vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'bin 02' or vw_public_request_material_location_mir.result_name like 'pass')
 and (requestor like 'BUGANIM, RINAT' and employee_name like 'BUGANIM, RINAT')
  and  ( DateDiff(DD,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_request].created_datetime, getdate()) < 30)
and ((substring(vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments,12,6)) like vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id
  or vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments like 'Changed by Matrix Transaction Handler' or vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments like 'Unit Ownership:%' 
  or vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.comments like  '%')
  and (unit_number = vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_name or unit_number is null)
  and (vortex_dbo.vw_public_material_location.material_id = vw_public_material_history.material_id )

  and material_name like 'D71G8V8900049'
```

Data that return is:

```
material_name   material_request_id parttype_name   operation_code  result_name qdf_number  requestor   recipient_name  created_by  time1   WW  product_code_name   task_name   full_location_name
D71G8V8900049   329136  H6 4SXDYV K U   7295    BIN 01  QPCR    BUGANIM, RINAT  Nicola, Michael mir_interface   2017-11-15 09:35:18.520 46  CANNON LAKE U 2+2   PPV-M   WFIQ: FROM WIP
D71G8V8900049   330463  H6 4SXDYV K U   7295    BIN 01  QPCR    BUGANIM, RINAT  Nicola, Michael SMS_Interface   2017-11-22 16:30:53.693 47  CANNON LAKE U 2+2   PPV-M   ACTIVE: NPP REALLOCATION
```

in addition there is any option to store current data at temp table and make additional filters on it?

Thanks!

Comment: so you want `max(material_request_id)` per `material_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I mark your result as a `tab(material_name, material_request_id, ...)` then rows with highest `material_request_id` per `material_name` can be retrieved using the following command

```
 with tab as (
    -- your query comes here
 )
 select tab.*
 from tab
 join
 (
   --subquery
   select material_name, max(material_request_id) max_request_id
   from tab
   group by material_name
 ) t on t.material_name = tab.material_name and 
        t.max_request_id = tab.material_request_id
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server) you can find a similar question/answers together with some performance comparison with a solution using window function.

The subquery finds highest `material_request_id` per `material_name` (you can run it separately to see). Then you simply join it with your result, where you select just rows satisfying the `t.max_request_id = tab.material_request_id`, therefore, selecting just those rows with highest `material_request_id` per `material_name`.

Comment: thanks! you may help me to understand how I should implement in in my query, its so long and busy and I'm not sure from where to start.

Comment: ITS great!! thanks a lot.. I will add more data to see if it gave full cover.

Comment: @Avi22 one more comment: do not hesitate to accept the answer to your question if it helps (not only this one but generally), that is the best way to say thank you on SO ;)

Comment: sure, :) if you can it will be possible to send me short explanation for how the solution works?, spicily the join with group by.