# Query to get multiple columns by group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table CR which has acc_id, cr_id,start_time as columns

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| cr_id |acc_id |start_time|
+-------+-------+----------+
| 1     | 100   |12.30 am  |
| 2     | 200   | 1.30 am  |
| 3     | 300   |10.30 am  |
| 4     | 300   | 8.30 am  |
| 5     | 200   | 9.30 am  |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

I want to get the acc_id, and cr_id which has max start_time for particular acc_id 
Result for above table with acc_id 200 and 300 should be

```
+-------+-------+
| cr_id |acc_id |
+-------+-------+
| 5     | 200   |
| 3     | 300   |
+----+------+----
```

I tried with below query but is giving all records

```
SELECT ACC_ID 
  CR_ID
FROM  CR
WHERE START_TIME IN
  (SELECT MAX(START_tIME)
  FROM CR
  WHERE ACC_ID in (100,200)
  GROUP BY ACC_ID
  );
```

Comment: What type is the `start_time` column?  Is that text?

Comment: The Type for start_time is date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
SELECT MIN(cr.cr_id) AS cr_id, cr.acc_id
FROM cr
WHERE acc_id IN (100, 200)
AND cr.start_time IN
(SELECT MAX(sub.start_time)
 FROM cr sub
 WHERE cr.acc_id = sub.acc_id)
GROUP BY cr.acc_id
```

You are very close in your attempt. The line you are missing is the check that the acc_id in your main query matches the acc_id in the sub-query.

Update: if you do not the same acc_id returned multiple times if there are multiple records with the max start time, you can select the acc_id with the cr_id that is first alphabetically, using MIN.

Comment: No need for GROUP BY in sub-query, since it is correlated.

Comment: @kbball: this will get me result for all acc_id. I want specifically for acc_id 100 and 200 here

Comment: @sujays there is an easy fix for that. See the update.

Comment: @kbball this query works correctly when the start_time values are different. if the start_time values are same for an acc_id then it gives multiple data. Can we just get the first record in case of this situation for an acc?

Comment: @sujays. Sure, a simple GROUP BY on acc_id will do something similar. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Use join and subquery. Assuming that `start_time` is a `timestamp` data type.

```
SELECT CR.*
FROM  CR
(
    SELECT ACC_ID, MAX(start_time) max_start_time
    FROM CR
    WHERE ACC_ID in (100,200)
    GROUP BY ACC_ID
) t ON t.acc_id = cr.acc_id and
       t.max_start_time = cr.start_time
```

It is possible to solve it also window functions, however, this solution allows the optimizer to use indexes [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server) (if they are available).