# Make SQL Server database "view" only show the duplicate rows which has column with the biggest specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

So for example I have a table with these 5 rows in a database:

```
Test1 ‌ ‌ ‌ C1 ‌ ‌ ‌ 143 ‌ ‌ ‌ 1
Test1 ‌ ‌ ‌ C1 ‌ ‌ ‌ 110 ‌ ‌ ‌ 3
Test2 ‌ ‌ ‌ C2 ‌ ‌ ‌ 923 ‌ ‌ ‌ 6
Test2 ‌ ‌ ‌ C2 ‌ ‌ ‌ 123 ‌ ‌ ‌ 9
Test2 ‌ ‌ ‌ C2 ‌ ‌ ‌ 332 ‌ ‌ ‌ 3
```

I want a view to ignore the third column and based on column 1 and 2 collect similar rows and omit the lower valued ones based on 4th column, to get a result like this:

```
Test1 ‌ ‌ ‌ C1 ‌ ‌ ‌ 110 ‌ ‌ ‌ 3
Test2 ‌ ‌ ‌ C2 ‌ ‌ ‌ 123 ‌ ‌ ‌ 9
```

Is this possible with SQL Server's database views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite standard solution is to use a aggregation and `JOIN`

```
select dat.*
from dat
join
(
    select c1, c2, max(c4) max_c4
    from dat
    group by c1, c2
) t on dat.c1 = t.c1 and
    dat.c2 = t.c2 and 
    dat.c4 = t.max_c4
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=41e13e32ecda19b410f96b3a5c11c72d)

Another solution would be using window function, however, it may be unnecessary slow in [certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-on-row-on-the-same-table-sql-server).

Comment: The query worked great with a tiny change to suit my needs thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery with min(col4) group by col1, col2  and use inner join  for get the all columns value related

```
select * from my_table m 
inner join ( 
select col1, col2,  min(col4)
my_table
group by col1, col2 ) t on m.col1 = t.col1 and m.col2= t.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using substrings and generating the demo data:

```
WITH mydata(a,b,c,d) as 
 (
 select * from 
 (
 VALUES ('teste1','c1',143,1),
  ('teste1','c1',110,3),
  ('teste2','c2',923,6),
  ('teste2','c2',123,9),
  ('teste2','c2',332,3)
 ) as x(a, b , d, e)
 )
select distinct a,b,(select top 1 max(d) from mydata d1 where d1.a= d2.a and d1.b = d2.b) from mydata d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the version of your SQL Server support the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function?

```
WITH
  v AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY e DESC) n
    FROM(
      VALUES('teste1', 'c1', 143, 1),
            ('teste1', 'c1', 110, 3),
            ('teste2', 'c2', 923, 6),
            ('teste2', 'c2', 123, 9),
            ('teste2', 'c2', 332, 3)
    ) t(a, b, d, e)
  )
SELECT a, b, d, e
FROM v
WHERE n = 1;
```

Check it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/LGQZ93385)