# sql select last but one record from every group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with building up following query:
I have a joined table from a selection query:

```
select nevlista.nevID as ColA, nkhk.nevktghID as ColB, nkhk.ktghelyID as ColC 
from nevlista
inner join nkhk on nevlista.nevID = nkhk.nevID
where nevlista.nevID = nkhk.nevID
```

This gives following result:

```
 ColA   ColB ColC
 90002  629 6
 90003  835 9
 90003  875 12
 90003  112 12
 90004  424 17
 90004  570 1
 90004  905 17
 90005  648 1
 90005  649 17
 90005  523 17
 and so on...
```

Now, I need from every group of same ID-s in ColA, the last but one highest value from ColB (and the value from ColC). (The number of same ID-s in ColA are different, usually there are 2 to 5 records with the same ID).

Comment: Could you add the right resultset for your demo data? I think it'll help to understand what you want.

Comment: the right resultset would be: 90003 - 835, 90004 - 570, 90005 - 648, ... the answer of Zohar Peled worked for me with "where rn = 2". But I think your solution would work too, I'll test it later.  Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is a cte with `Row_number` partitioned by colA ordered by colB desc:

```
;With cte as
(
    select  nevlista.nevID as ColA, 
            nkhk.nevktghID as ColB, 
            nkhk.ktghelyID as ColC,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nevlista.nevID ORDER BY nkhk.nevktghID DESC) as rn
    from nevlista
    inner join nkhk on nevlista.nevID = nkhk.nevID
    where nevlista.nevID = nkhk.nevID
)

select ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 2 -- assiming every nevlista.nevID appears at least twice in the cte
```

Comment: With rn = 2 it gives me the last but one highest value of ColB for each group, so this could be it! Thank you!

Comment: What if you have a nevID value that only exists in a single row?

Comment: that would not occur in the query-result but in my data-environment this is fortunately not a problem. (for now.... )

Answer (score 2):

You could use ranking function `row_number()` with *ties* method

```
select top(1) with ties nl.nevID as cola, n.nevktghID as colb, n.ktghelyID as colc
from nevlista nl 
inner join nkhk n on nl.nevID = n.nevID
order by row_number() over (partition by nl.nevID order by n.nevktghID  desc)
```

And, i suspect there would be no need to use `where` clause after `joins`

Comment: A good idea! I've never tried to use `ROW_NUMBER` in `ORDER BY` block.

Comment: I keep forgetting about `with ties`... Good point about the where clause as well. +1

Comment: This also gives the highest value of ColB. I need the last but one highest, but I don't know how to change this query to get that.

Comment: @ajudi last? how do you recognize last if not by highest value? there is no implicit order in relation ...

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you, my english is not the best. Yes, the last one is the highest but I don't need the highest, I need the one before the highest, for example, for 90003 in ColA it would be 835 in ColB. So I guess one step needed is to get ColB in the right order (is this the implicit order?) in each group and then select the second record of each group.

Comment: @ajudi you should read some text about relational data model (probably in your language)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `group by` with `max`:

```
select nevlista.nevID as ColA, nkhk.nevktghID as ColB, nkhk.ktghelyID as ColC 
from nevlista
join nkhk on nevlista.nevID = nkhk.nevID
join
(
    select nevID, max(nevktghID) max_nevktghID
    from nkhk 
    group by nevID
) t1 on nkhk.nevID = t1.nevID and
        nkhk.nevktghID = t1.max_nevktghID
```

It can be [considerably faster on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server) mainly if you have the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_nkhk _nevID_nevktghID
  ON nkhk (nevID,nevktghID) INCLUDE (ktghelyID)
```