# How do I use max date on SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have sql query question as;

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
aaaa, 2018.11.06, 8.0, 400.0
aaaa, 2018.06.06, 12.0, 600.0
aaaa, 2018.02.10, 10.0, 500.0
bbbb, 2017.11.06, 8.0, 100.0
bbbb, 2017.06.06, 12.0, 300.0
bbbb, 2017.02.10, 10.0, 200.0
```

In select statement I need to get only biggest (newest) Col2. The correct result must be:

```
aaaa, 2018.11.06, 8.0, 400.0
bbbb, 2017.11.06, 8.0, 100.0
```

because 2018.11.06 and 2017.11.06 is the biggest(newest).

How do I use max date on SQL query on MS SQL or ORACLE?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: both MS SQL and Oracle

Comment: google `SQL ORDER BY`

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two rows with that date 2018.11.06 ?

Comment: Yes true, if there are two rows with that date 2018.11.06 than Col1 will be different

Comment: @Nick so you are looking for a newest `col2` per `col1`?

Comment: yes ture newest col2 for per col1

Comment: Add some more sample data (with different col1 values), and adjust the expected result!

Comment: jarlh I update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a universal solution can be

```
select yt.*
from your_table yt
join (
   select col1, max(col2) max_col2
   from your_table
   group by col1
) t on t.col1 = yt.col1 and
       t.max_col2 = yt.col2
```

this solution will return all rows with the maximal date per `col1`. Another solution is to use the row_numer(), however, it can have [suboptimal performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server).

```
select *
from
(
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) rn
  from your_table
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: I did similar but I get only 1 row. There is a Col1 which has aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc .... I need to get max date for each Col1

Comment: @nick updated in order to look for greatest per group

Comment: @nick post the exact problem

Comment: Baca thanks the universal solution worked both ms sql and pl sql. I had a mistake on line t.col1 = yt.col1 forget to put yt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a where col2 in 
   (select max(col2) from tablename b on a.col1=b.col1)
```

Comment: having problem on oracle

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable ORDER BY Col2 DESC
```

Comment: Easiest and best!