# How to take max date row for each imei

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which got some rows. From this rows I need to take all rows for each imei and for each date (without time) for report data. But always got 1 query, please can anybody help me? I'm not very familiar with SQL.

I have this table:

```
Id  Imei                CreationDate                  DeviceId
1   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-04 09:01:13.7202092   1
2   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-04 09:01:20.5318598   1
3   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-06 09:01:25.0101371   1
4   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-08 09:01:30.2557571   1
5   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-08 09:01:34.0354277   1
6   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-09 09:01:41.8190975   1
7   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-09 09:01:46.7797098   1
```

I want to have this table:

```
Id  Imei                CreationDate                  DeviceId
2   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-04 09:01:20.5318598   1
3   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-06 09:01:25.0101371   1
5   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-08 09:01:34.0354277   1
7   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-09 09:01:46.7797098   1
```

My current result:

```
Id  Imei                CreationDate                  DeviceId
7   ProductionDevice299 2018-11-09 09:01:46.7797098   1
```

My current MS SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[Imei] AS [imei], 
    [Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [lastSeenOnline],  
    [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [deviceId]
    FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [Imei], max([CreationDate]) as MaxDate
        FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory]
        GROUP BY [Imei]
    ) [Extent2] on [Extent1].[Imei] = [Extent2].[Imei] and [Extent1].[CreationDate] = [Extent2].MaxDate
```

Comment: Use group by imei and creation date (u will need to cast it to date) then select max(CreationDate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by a date (without time):

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[Imei] AS [imei], 
    [Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [lastSeenOnline],  
    [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [deviceId]
    FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [Imei], max([CreationDate]) as MaxDate
        FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory]
        GROUP BY [Imei]
          ,CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE) -- for each day
    ) [Extent2]
   on [Extent1].[Imei] = [Extent2].[Imei]
  and [Extent1].[CreationDate] = [Extent2].MaxDate
```

Casting as a date removes the time part.

You can also apply a Row_number, your Group By conditions are moved to Partition By:

```
with cte as 
 (
   SELECT *,
      row_number()
      over (partititon by [Imei], CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE)
            order by CreationDate) as rn
   FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]
 )
select id, 
   imei, 
   CreationDate AS lastSeenOnline, 
   DeviceId
from cte
where rn = 1
```

And for performance testing you can also try MIN:

```
with cte as 
 (
   SELECT *,
      min(CreationDate)
      over (partititon by [Imei], CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE)) as minDate
   FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]
 )
select id, 
   imei, 
   CreationDate AS lastSeenOnline, 
   DeviceId
from cte
where CreationDate = minDate
```

Comment: I saw in SO some answers with row_number(), but don't you know what will be faster to use? Inner join or row number.

Comment: @BorHunter The subquery solution is better on SQL Server, since it can efficiently use indexes that are available. The row_number() solution always uses the sequential scan. Here is a simple test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674876/select-corresponding-to-row-from-the-same-table-sql-server

Comment: The row_number is much more flexible when it's a more complex query including join or complex Where-conditions. The `CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE)` might not use an index, you should test both approaches (as always)

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(dh.id) as id, dh.Imei, MIN(dh.CreationDate) as CreationDate,
       dh.DeviceId
FROM DeviceHistory dh
GROUP BY dh.Imei, dh.DeviceId,
         CONVERT(DATE, dh.CreationDate);
```

This version makes the (reasonable) assumption that the `id`s and `creationdate` increase together.

If not, then I would recommend `row_number()`:

```
SELECT dh.*
FROM (SELECT dh.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dh.Imei, CONVERT(DATE, dh.CreationDate) ORDER BY dh.CreationDate) as seqnum
      FROM DeviceHistory dh
     ) dh
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```